# Accesing private variable from abstract class with access method as abstract

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class called book that is abstract, has a private variable price, and also has it's getter method as abstract.

```java
    public abstract class Book{

        private double price;

        public abstract double getPrice();

    }
```

Now let's say I have a used Book class that inherits all of Book's attributes, but also has an age associated with it. Also I want this class to override the getPrice method from it's parent class. This is where I get stuck since the price variable is private, and the parent class has an abstract getter method.

```java
    public class UsedBook extends Book{

        private int age;

        //constructor
        public UsedBook(){
            age = 1;
        }

        @Override
        public double getPrice(){
            //How can I implement this method so as a user I can access the price?
        }

    }
```

Thank You

Comment: You can do yourself and the whole jdk a favor by changing **private double price;** to **protected double price;** if you are NOT interested in providing public access to this variable, but since UsedBook is meant to extend Book, you better change your access modifier from private to protected. This will ensure that the rules of inheritance will remain intact

Comment: So there would be no way as a user to get access to price as explained above? I would either have to change the variable price to protected, or make the accessor in book not abstract. Correct? I appreciate everyone's speedy responses.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that if `price` is in the abstract superclass, then `getPrice()` ***cannot*** be abstract in that class.  It must be concrete and implement the getter function because that is where the data element is defined.  It makes zero sense for `getPrice()` to be abstract.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all implementations of `Book` must implement `getPrice()`, and the implementation is always to just return the price, it should not be abstract. You should just define the getter within your abstract class:

```
public abstract class Book{

    private double price;

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

}//Ends book class
```

If this doesn't work, and you need to directly access the `price` variable from inheriting classes, then you should change it to be `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: You can still override the `getPrice` method using this advice, and get the `price` value within the override by calling `super.getPrice()`. Many consider this a best practice, rather than making the variable `protected`. You should resist making fields non-`private`.

Comment: @LewBloch Good point. I can definitely see how that would lead to cleaner design in some cases.

Answer (score 9):

If you do not want the `price` field variable to be publicly accessible from the **Abstract** class then, you should change the access modifier from `private` to `protected`.

**protected** access modifier means that the field isn't publicly accessible via instance object. However any subclass that inherits the **Abstract** class *directly* or *indirectly* has the `protected` fields inherited as a field variable, and the same rules goes apply, it cannot be publicly accessible.

So to wrapped it up, the **Book** class:

```
public abstract class Book {
  protected double price;

  public abstract double getPrice();
}
```

The subclass that inherits the **Book** class:

```
public class UsedBook extends Book{

  private int age;

  public UsedBook(){
    this.age = 1;
    this.price = 0; // You should also set the field variable from the abstract "Book" class
  }

  @Override
  public double getPrice(){
    return this.price;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mark price as protected then you can access to it from sub classes :

```
public abstract class Book{

    protected double price;

    public abstract double getPrice();

}

public class UsedBook extends Book{

...

    @Override
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

..

}
```