# Parent class access modifier

Tags: c#, inner-classes, access-modifiers

I have an abstract `ParentClass` which contains a private `PrivateThing` class which I don't want to expose to derived classes, to which I instead provide `ThingContainer`.

However, there's no access modifier to make `ThingContainer.Things` visible to `ParentClass`;

`protected`/`internal`:

- results in a compiler error, since `PrivateThing` is private.
- would expose `ThingContainer.Things` to derived classes as well, which is undesireable.

Is there a way to make `ThingContainer.Things` visible to the `ParentClass` without exposing `PrivateThing`?

```cs
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    private sealed class PrivateThing { }

    protected sealed class ThingContainer
    {
        private List<PrivateThing> _things = new();

        // Should be visible to ParentClass
        private IReadOnlyList<PrivateThing> Things => _things;

        public void AddThing()
        {
            _things.Add(new PrivateThing());
        }
    }


    private readonly List<ThingContainer> _thingContainers = new();

    protected void Setup(Action<ThingContainer> setupThings)
    {
        var container = new ThingContainer();
        setupThings(container);
        _thingContainers.Add(container);
    }

    public void ProcessThings()
    {
        foreach (var thing in _thingContainers.SelectMany(static b => b.Things /* Can't access */))
            Console.WriteLine(thing.ToString());
    }
}

public sealed class DerivedClass : ParentClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {
        Setup(static things =>
        {
            things.AddThing();
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: Answered by Ralf in the comments, thanks!

Comment: Make ThingContainer an abstract method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332709/accesing-private-variable-from-abstract-class-with-access-method-as-abstract

Comment: Make PrivateThing and ProcessThings part of the Container and the surfaced ProcessThings method just forward to the then existing Container.ProcessThings implementation.

Comment: @GHDevOps Thanks, that was my initial implementation, however I have to keep track of the order the things are added by the derived classes (`ThingContainer` per derived class allows me to do that).
@Ralf I didn't think about that, that seems like a good solution, thanks.

Comment: And as a sidenote for others, I just found out about `private protected`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected